# How can I add a div after every 3 div.class's with content being dynamically added?

Tags: php

I have a dynamic/responsive website that allows the user to add blocks of text content and it will form into a grid. I've changed it a little for the sake of the question and just added some content as if it were already added on the page.

I want to add a `<div>` after every third `div.test-content` (`$test`).

```
    <?php
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 1!</p>';
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 2!</p>';
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 3!</p>';

        // display $timage
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 4!</p>';
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 5!</p>';

        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 6!</p>';
        // display $timage
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 7!</p>';

        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 8!</p>';
        $test[] = '<p>Tesimonial text 9!</p>';
        // display $timage
        shuffle($test);

        $timage[] = '<p>NUMBER 1!</p>';
        $timage[] = '<p>NUMBER 2!</p>';
        $timage[] = '<p>NUMBER 3!</p>';
        shuffle($timage);
    ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php 
        foreach($test as $value){
            echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. $value .'</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

At the moment that code should shuffle `$test` and display the results, I want to display `$timage` after every 3rd `$test`.

Comment: I don't understand how my question was voted down, especially after 2 minutes, it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: That's because it is considered to be a very basic question one can quite easily solve by checking some tutorial on how to work with loops.

Comment: @Julian I'm not very good with PHP, I didn't know this was considered to be basic, but I looked it up I don't really know where to start.

Comment: @Julian I'm not having any luck figuring this out, I thought this was supposed to be easy haha... maybe you'd like to help?

Comment: Either use the solution provided by Drea58 or go with a `for`-style loop. Then do the check either by testing if your counter variable is at a specific value then resetting it, or by going with modulo (= division remainder) like in Drea58's solution.

Comment: Well his solution helped but it doesn't answer the question, atm I display every `$timage` after 3 `div.test-content`'s. Not sure how to just make that display 1 random $timage at a time, you suggested a counter variable? What if we take all of the `$timage`'s and shuffle those into `$timage1`, `$timage2`, etc and then use said counter variable to display them in order from `$timage1` and on in each the `if (key % 3 = 2){ //here }`?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with @Julian - the point is that voting is anonymous, so unless people explain why they are downvoting, the answer is "we don't know". IMO it is not appropriate to downvote people for asking a beginner question, but it is fine to downvote for not demonstrating prior research or not searching for the problem (not saying that's the case here, mind you). FWIW questions _ideally_ should contain an attempt, even if the OP cannot finish it.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for explaining, that is fair. I think it would be better if it required you give a reason for down voting, at least after already being down voted one time. Any ways I understand I could have done some more research, this is what I had so far and I just didn't know what to do next, I did do a bit of Googling though but turned up nothing - it also helps to know what to Google haha.

Comment: @mattroberts: someone has [already thought of that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-an-explanation-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question), and I think the answer is 'no'. Also, [this is related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulo operator on the key:

```
<?php 
foreach($test as $key => $value){
    echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. $value .'</div>';
    if( $key % 3 == 2 ) {
        echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. $timage[intval($key/3)] .'</div>';            
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where you've written 'echo stuff', should I add another `foreach($timage as $tvalue){ echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. $tvalue .'</div>'; }`?

Comment: Or is it possible for $test = $value but if ($key % 3 == 2) then $timage = $value instead of $test? (I'm really weak with this stuff lol)

Comment: do you want to show the images AFTER each 3rd row or INSTEAD every third row ?

Comment: I want to show it after every 3rd .test-content, not instead of.

Comment: add another foreach() inside the if.
Simply try and see what happens.

Comment: It shuffles all $timage and places them all after every 3rd div.test-content, how would I make it only show 1 at a time?

Comment: you know what a foreach-loop is doing? if you dont want to echo all, remove the foreach and echo only one item. I suppose you want a random one? use php's rand()-function.

Comment: I realized after haha, so just `rand($timage as $tvalue){ echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. $tvalue .'</div>'; }` or something like `echo '<div class="medium-6 large-4 columns test-content">'. rand($timage) .'</div>';`? I'm just not sure how to write it.

Comment: maybe have a look in the documentation on how to use rand() http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't do much for me. Is there a way to set a counter for each `$timage` and display 1 random one at a time using `rand()`?

Comment: Forget about rand, since you already shuffled the array. I missed that somehow. I've edited my answer.